# Date and time in JavaScript with moment.js and moment-timezone.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to display `date and time` in input fields. In the first one `datetime value` of start of a day, and in second one `datetime value` of the end of a day. I use `moment.js` and `moment-timezone.js`

- [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)
- [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

### Problem

From `00:00:00` to `02:59:59` every day code shows unexpected results.
Code shows previous day instead of current day.
Here is [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/90tov5h2/4/).

In order to see what exactly I mean please open browser console and set your time to anything from `00:00:00` to `02:59:59` and region to `Europe/Riga`.

This problem shows on `Windows 10 Pro` and current Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

### Code

```
$(function() {
    var myTime = moment(new Date()).utc().toDate();
    myTime = moment(myTime).tz("Europe/Riga").format();
    console.log('myTime = '+ myTime);

    var startOfDay = moment().utc().startOf('day').subtract(3, 'h').toDate();
    var endOfDay = moment().utc().endOf('day').subtract(3, 'h').toDate();
    console.log('startOfDay = '+ startOfDay);
    console.log('endOfDay   = '+ endOfDay);
    startOfDay = moment(startOfDay).tz("Europe/Riga").format();
    endOfDay = moment(endOfDay).tz("Europe/Riga").format();
    console.log('startOfDay = '+ startOfDay);
    console.log('endOfDay   = '+ endOfDay);
    document.getElementById('date_from').value = startOfDay;
    document.getElementById('date_to').value = endOfDay;
});
```

### Console output

```
{--- console output start --------------------------------}
myTime = 2016-08-29T01:56:37+03:00
startOfDay = Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
endOfDay   = Sun Aug 28 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
startOfDay = 2016-08-28T00:00:00+03:00
endOfDay   = 2016-08-28T23:59:59+03:00
{--- console output end --------------------------------}
```

As one can see `myTime` is set to 29th of August, but `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` still returns 28th of August.

- Is there something I do wrong?
- Am I missing something here?
- Or is it a bug?

### Update

working code without `utc()` and `subtract(3, 'h')`

```
$(function() {
    var myTime = moment().toDate();
    myTime = moment(myTime).tz("Europe/Riga").format();
    console.log('myTime = '+ myTime);

    var startOfDay = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
    var endOfDay = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
    console.log('startOfDay = '+ startOfDay);
    console.log('endOfDay   = '+ endOfDay);
    startOfDay = moment(startOfDay).tz("Europe/Riga").format();
    endOfDay = moment(endOfDay).tz("Europe/Riga").format();
    console.log('startOfDay = '+ startOfDay);
    console.log('endOfDay   = '+ endOfDay);
    document.getElementById('date_from').value = startOfDay;
    document.getElementById('date_to').value = endOfDay;
});
```

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Comment: I think that you are using [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) wrong, maybe docs of  [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) can help you. It's not a bug, you see the issue between 00:00 and 02:59 because your local time (`Europe/Riga`) has +3 hours offset from UTC.

Comment: If i remove `subtract(3, 'h')` It gets time that is set 3 hours in the future. As I need time from midnight (00:00:00) to midnight (23:59:59), but the time that shows without `subtract(3, 'h')` is not correct (2016-08-29T03:00:00+03:00 and 2016-08-30T02:59:59+03:00).

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC, indeed - I did not need `utc()` in the code.